# Perl :what does "-" means in perl

Tags: perl

what does '-' mean in the param

```
$cgi->start_html(-title => uc($color), -BGCOLOR => $color);
```

I just know it is used in hash type, but this is param in a sub. So it makes me confused, and i searched for a long time.

Comment: Please don't use CGI,pm if you have any choice in the matter. Something based on PSGI/Plack will make your life so much easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you come across confusing syntax in Perl, a handy tool is the `-MO=Deparse` option.  This causes Perl to check the syntax of a script and output the script in a normalized form, rather than executing it.

So if I do

```
perl -MO=Deparse -e '$cgi->start_html(-title => uc($color), -BGCOLOR => $color);'
```

I get a result of:

```
$cgi->start_html(-'title', uc $color, -'BGCOLOR', $color);
-e syntax OK
```

There are three differences here:

1. Quotes were added to `title` and `BGCOLOR`.
2. The `=>` operators changed to commas.
3. The parentheses disappeared from `uc($color)`.

The first two are the normal effects of the [`=>` ("fat comma")](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Comma-Operator) operator: It's equivalent to a comma, except that if the thing to the left is an identifier (starting with a letter or underscore and containing only alphanumeric characters and underscores), that identifier becomes a quoted string.

And the parentheses after `uc` just aren't strictly necessary in this situation, since the builtin function `uc` is prototyped to take 0 or 1 arguments.

But now we have `-'title'` and `-'BGCOLOR'`, so what's the negative of a string?  Checking [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators), we see that unary minus follows the rules:

1. If the operand is a number or a string representation of a number, does an arithmetic negation.
2. Otherwise, if the string starts with `'+'` or `'-'`, switches just the first character of the string to the opposite sign.
3. Otherwise, if the string starts with a letter, adds a `'-'` to the beginning of the string.
4. Otherwise, attempts to convert the string to a number, probably prints a warning if warnings are enabled, and then does an arithmetic negation.

Here we have case 3, so `-'title'` is `'-title'` and `-'BGCOLOR'` is `'-BGCOLOR'`.

So presumably the `start_html` method expects a list of arguments which come in key-value pairs, and the key strings are supposed to start with hyphens.  (It might or might not internally use these arguments to create a hash, with a line like `my %options = @_;`.)

This is all a little roundabout, plus you'd get confusing results if you ever tried passing something like `-3zzz => $value`.  So I'd personally add explicit quotes here to make it obvious what's being passed, but keep using the fat commas anyway to emphasize the arguments are meant to be key/value pairs:

```
$cgi->start_html('-title' => uc($color), '-BGCOLOR' => $color);
```

Comment: why the key strings start with hyphens? And when i use hyphens? what is the difference between the key strings without hyphens?

Comment: Nothing. They're just strings.

Answer (score 3):

It has no effect here. It's just treated as part of the string. I assume that the original author of CGI.pm wanted to make the options look more like command-line options. I think that was a terrible idea.

Comment: I agree it was not the best idea but it's not so uncommon and other modules use that convention as well. The first time I saw it I had the same question as the OP and wondered why they would use only _one_ dash, not _two_ (like in --real-long-options). I think it doesn't work then without `'--quoting'`.

Comment: @PerlDuck: I don't think I use any other modules that use this convention (of course, I don't use CGI.pm very often these days either).

Answer (score 1):

It's a string literal, just like "-title" or "-BGCOLOR".

Answer (score 1):

[`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Symbolic-Unary-Operators):

> [Unary `"-"` ...] If the operand is an identifier, a string consisting of a minus sign concatenated with the identifier is returned. Otherwise, if the string starts with a plus or minus, a string starting with the opposite sign is returned.

In other words, `-"foo"` is `"-foo"`.

> The `=>` operator (sometimes pronounced "fat comma") is a synonym for the comma except that it causes a word on its left to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a letter or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores.

In other words, `foo => 42` is `"foo", 42`.

Taken together, this means `-title => uc($color)` is `"-title", uc($color)`.